# Unable to truly background an SSH tunnel using Fabric and nohup

Tags: python, bash, ssh, fabric, nohup

I can't seem to get Fabric to play nice with backgrounding a process that I've used nohup on. . . It should be possible, given various pieces of information, including [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/216) and [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang).

```
def test():
h = 'xxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'    
ports = [16646, 9090, 6666]

with settings(host_string = h):
    tun_s = "ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/kp.pem %s@%s " % (env.user, h)      

    for port in ports:
        p_forward = "-L %d:localhost:%d" % (port, port)
        tun_s = "%s %s" % (tun_s, p_forward)

    tun_s = "%s -N" % tun_s
    # create the tunnel. . .
    print "creating tunnel %s" % tun_s
    run("nohup '%s' >& /dev/null < /dev/null &" % tun_s)
    print "fin"
```

Abbreviated output:

```
ubuntu@domU-xxx:~/deploy$ fab test
executing on tunnel ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/kp.pem ubuntu@xxx  -L 16646:localhost:16646 -L 9090:localhost:9090 -L 6666:localhost:6666 -N
[xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com] run: nohup 'ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/kp.pem ubuntu@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com  -L 16646:localhost:16646 -L 9090:localhost:9090 -L 6666:localhost:6666 -N' >& /dev/null < /dev/null &
fin

Done.
Disconnecting from xxxx
```

I know there is no problem with the tunnel command per se because if I strip away the nohup stuff it works fine (but obviously Fabric hangs). I'm pretty sure that it's not properly getting detached and when the run function returns the tunnel process is immediately dying.

But why?

This also happens with a python command in another part of my code.

Comment: Why _are you_ using nohup? it's redundant if you ask me.

Comment: Hmm, did you try disabling tty allocation of ssh with -T, and also disabling tty allocation for the task with pty=False?

Comment: @sehe, why is it redundant? How else should I be detaching the process so that Fabric can return without the tunnel dying?

Comment: @Edwardr I'm not into Fabric, but ssh backgrounds itself on -N, which is enough for me to be able to exit the shell, logout, terminate the XServer without affecting a tunnel started in that fashion.

Comment: @favoretti I tried both of those but no dice. Thanks.

Comment: @Edwardr You want to start a tunnel to execute a command over it later on, or do you want to just start a tunnel? There's a fabric tunneling proposal here: https://gist.github.com/856179

Comment: @sehe If I use -f -N for the tunnel and none of the nohup stuff, the tunnel is not left running (I don't know the mechanics of why), but it's something to do with the way Fabric works.

Comment: @favoretti I want to just start a tunnel on the remote host to somewhere else. Why is it that Fabric kills the ssh tunnel when I use -f -N???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems after much wrangling that this is not possible for whatever reason with my setup (default Ubuntu installs on EC2 instances). I have no idea why and as it seems possible according to various sources.

I fixed my particular problem by using [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) in place of Fabric, for calls that need to be left running in the background. The following achieves this:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('xxx.pem')
ssh.connect('xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com', username='ubuntu', pkey=privkey)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("nohup ssh  -f -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i     ~/.ssh/xxx.pem ubuntu@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -L 16646:localhost:16646 -L -N >& /dev/null < /dev/null &")
ssh.close()
```